# Does the ServiceAccount token need to remain secret?

Tags: go, kubernetes

In a pod, a ServiceAccount token will be auto-mounted to `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`. There are some [blog articles](https://learnk8s.io/microservices-authentication-kubernetes) that suggest using ServiceAccounts to perform service to service authentication.

Those articles basically suggest sending the unmodified token to the service being called as an HTTP header. The called service can then implement validating the callers identity using `k8s.io/api/authentication` Go API.

But doesn't the token need to be kept secret? Naively I'd think that the called service can misuse the token to impersonate the calling service (by making API calls using its token).

Is this a legitimate concern? Or is there something build into K8s that makes sure only the pod into which the token has been mounted can use it to make API calls?

Comment: There is nothing that prevents the called service from using the service account token. You can use the token yourself from outside the cluster to authenticate to the API.

Comment: How would a service get the SA token if it's not mounted into the pod? Obviously, the token is secret information, that's why it's mounted on a need-to-know basis.

Comment: Tokens are stored as a secret, which means that every service account needs a secret from Kubernetes. Because of how secretes are managed by Kubernetes, any component that has permission to see one of a service account's secrets can see all of them. While the egress controller is required to read TLS secrets, it is also able to read the service account credentials for each cluster application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few folks basically answered the question but used comments. So let me answer the question myself.

The token can be used to impersonate the service sending it. It can even be used outside the cluster to authenticate to the API.

There also doesn't seem to be machinery in the K8S API to use public key mechanisms, to avoid having to reveal the token.

Overall, sending the token to anyone else seems like a really bad idea. I would advise not to use the approach outlined in the blog post linked to in the question.